# How can I call a function after an event is resolved in another client-side module?

Tags: javascript, events

I'm a beginner. I'm creating an app that relies on an in-browser editor, in this case monaco editor.

The editor has this event which occurs after an editor is created:

```
monaco.editor.onDidCreateModel(()=>{
    initBoard();
})
```

Within, I have called a function `initBoard()` which inits some critical actions in my `main` file. This way however I have some circular imports, and I'm importing from `main` which I have now found to be bad coding practices.

Instead I want some other way of having the effect of calling `initBoard()` without having to import from main.

What is typically the best pattern for getting a function in `main` to call from a module?

Comment: Does your main code *call* the module code that creates the editor? If so, pass a callback.

Comment: It doesn't at the moment, but can be made to. I see what you mean, that's a neat way of doing it, thanks!